# CSS transform: scale doesn't work on iPhones 7, 8, etc

Tags: css, ios, iphone, safari, responsive-design

I have website - 55carats.com , there is last section (before footer) with Instagram posts, this is Wordpress plugins customized via my css theme file. It has responsive design for mobiles - slider with arrows (no swipe, click only), it should look like thing on this screen, image with arrows on sides
[Right appearance of section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYRpx.png)
But on old iPhones (or even all iPhones, I can't say) CSS transform: scale(x) property doesn't work and arrows stay on the top of the image. On iPhone 13 for no reasons everything works fine, I don't think this is causes by browser/system support cause the 8th iPhone has IOS 13.1 and it should work pretty fine there.
[Wrong appearance of section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89oTf.png)
I have webkit prefixes in styles, there are stylesheet. I also added height in absolute value (px) to the parent element because I thought maybe Safari can't scale the div because it has no absolute height, but that didn't work.
Sorry if this is a duplicate, I found nothing on web that could help me there, thanks everyone in advance.

```css
.sbi_item {
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: scale(68%);
        -moz-transform: scale(68%);
        -ms-transform: scale(68%);
        -o-transform: scale(68%);
        transform: scale(68%);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `-webkit-transform: scale(0.68);`? I think webkit is weird about percentages

Comment: Thank you! This really helped, now I don't even know why this was working in other browsers

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you why it's like that. I haven't been able to find anything that explicitly states that you have to use a decimal value but I know I've seen this question come up a few times and that's usually what it is.